# Tool to label images for classification

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, training

Can anyone recommend a tool to quickly label several hundred images as an input for classification?

I have ~500 microscopy images of cells. I would like to assign categories such as `'healthy'`, `'dead'`, `'sick'` manually for a training set and save those to a csv file.

Basically, the same as described in [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/build-a-tool-for-manually-classifying-training-data-images) question, except I do not have proprietary images, so maybe that opens up additional possibilities?

Comment: Is this something that you will have to do several times?  If so, it might be worth building a tool.  See this: http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13335/build-a-tool-for-manually-classifying-training-data-images?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Might go that route if necessary but it seemed like something many people might use and for which a solution already exists?

Comment: It sounds like pilab-annotator or pylabelme are usefull, they might be overkill though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609455/image-sequence-annotation-tool

Comment: those seem geared towards annotating features within images. Maybe I could use them in the most basic way to just assign one label to the entire image

Comment: Any photo organizer software that supports tags?

Comment: any specific suggestions that would support export of filename along with tags to csv?

Comment: There a few tools out there for image annotation, the most popular and easy to use one is: https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just hacked together a very basic helper in python
it requires that all images are stored in a pyton list `allImages`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
category=[]
plt.ion()

for i,image in enumerate(allImages):
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.pause(0.05)
    category.append(raw_input('category: '))
```

Comment: If this solved your issue, you should accept your own answer so it doesn't appear as an "unanswered question" on this website :)

Answer (score 6):

### pidgey - widget for jupyter notebook with active learning

I have just found this [open-source tool](https://github.com/wbwvos/pidgey), and it looks amazing:
[image]

It's an interactive widget for Jupyter Notebook and the best thing about it - according to [this commit](https://github.com/wbwvos/pidgey/commit/6a899cf7bce8dd9382b73589c14e20d8cbe1fcd7) **you can add your own sklearn-like classifier and use it for predicting classes as you annotate!** The classifier keeps learning as you proceed with labeling.

---

#### tkteach - Super Fast Image Categorization Python Tool

Also, there is a tool called **tkteach** and it's great because you can annotate images really fast using only your keyboard. I have improved the original version a little bit. The fork is here: https://github.com/Serhiy-Shekhovtsov/tkteach

[image]

Comment: You can also try Simple Image Labeler if you something simple with keyboard shortcuts and that stores images in sub-directories instead of in a sqlite database https://github.com/marcsto/simple-image-labeler

Answer (score 5):

Try this tool. It is very simple and does exactly what you want → assign label(s) to images in a given folder.

https://github.com/robertbrada/PyQt-image-annotation-tool

[image]

Comment: You have built a great tool. Thank You.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is Great!  very useful.

Comment: Aewsome! I had to change `self.img_panel_width` and `self.img_panel_height` but is aewsome! Very usefull tool.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a code doing what you need, it is available on GitHub as [image-sorter2](https://github.com/Nestak2/image-sorter2). Instead of "labelling" images, it puts the images into a new folder, but creating the csv you are talking about is a straight forward extension. Compared to the other suggested scripts here image-sorter2 is 100% free of charges and you don't need to spend time on drawing bounding boxes - the script simply opens a GUI for you, you click on one of multiple buttons and correspondingly each image is sorted into the desired class-folder, e.g. "cats", "dogs", "trucks" a.s.o.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try [Supervisely](https://supervise.ly/).

For your task you could create classes: 'healthy', 'dead', 'sick' and associate them with Rectangle tool. Then you just put a box around each cell with corresponding class.
Below is an example:

1. Definitions of classes
   [image]
2. Labeling
   [image]

If your categories are not mutually exclusive, you may create “cell” class (and associate it with rectangle) and then create several tags - one for each of your categories.
Below is an example:

1. Definitions of classes and tags
   [image]
2. Labeling
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using EVA annotation tool. [Ericsson/eva](https://github.com/Ericsson/eva) ,this has an excellent tracking function. you mark the object in only 1 frame and rest/many of the frames are automatically annotated. This also has lock unlock feature to help annotate faster and more number of objects in each frame. This supports video upload or image data sets.

Best thing, completely Free/open source !
[image]